# Como funciona as Promises no Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, promises

Estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade de entender o funcionamento das ***Promises*** do Angularjs. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
function validateUser(name, pw) {

  var status = '';

  var data = {login: name, senha: pw, plataforma: 'APP'};

  $http.post('http://localhost:8100/login', data)
    .then(function(response) {

      console.log(response.data.retorno);

      var status = response.data.retorno;

    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err)
  });
}

function teste(name, pw) {

  var status = validateUser(nome, pw);
  alert(status);
  ...
}
```

O código funciona perfeitamente. Porém eu não consigo retornar a resposta de um `$http.post` para outra função. Eu apenas consigo ter a resposta dessa promise em `.then(function(){ ... }`

Em jQuery usavamos o `async: false` para solucionar esse problema. Existe algo parecido no Angularjs?

Comment: Você poderia colocar esse valor de retorno em uma variável do controller ou passá-la como parâmetro para uma outra função. Um callback, por exemplo.

Comment: Não é um "problema", é assim mesmo que funciona : ) Usar requisições síncronas (`async: false` no jquery) não é recomendado.

Comment: mas como eu faria para a minha function teste() esperar o retorno? Eu tentei seguir a documentação do angular e usar var deferred = $q.defer(); mas n tive sucesso!

Comment: O que você quer fazer (de verdade) com os dados, sem ser o alert?

Comment: @bfavaretto: Eu tenho a função validateUser() em meu arquivo services.js e tenho a função teste() dentro do meu controller.js. Eu quero receber esse retorno na minha controller para redirecionar o usuario para alguma página (dependendo do status do msm). Eu acho q n ficaria legal fazer esse redirecionamento dentro de services.js

Comment: Como estou começando a trabalhar com angularjs agora. Talvez a minha lógica n esteja correta. Não tenho certeza se devo usar o http.post dentro de services. Ou mudar a lógica por completo e usar dentro de controller.js

Comment: O recomendado é deixar o controller o mais limpo possível. Essa lógica das requisições pode ficar no service e apenas receber as chamadas do controller para ser tratado na view. Recomendo a leitura do styleguide adotado pela comunidade: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderia tentar fazer algo do tipo:

```
function validateUser(name, pw, callback) {

    var status = '';

    var data = {login: name, senha: pw, plataforma: 'APP'};
    $http.post('http://localhost:8100/login', data)
        .then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                callback(response.data);
            },
            function errorCallback(response){
                callback(response);
            }
        );
}

function teste(name, pw) {
    var status = validateUser(nome, pw, function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
    alert(status);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Valeu @Hamurabi Araujo. Era exatamente isso q eu n estava sabendo fazer! :)

Comment: Fico feliz de ter ajudado. Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição. Passei por um problema bem parecido alguns dias atrás ;)